# Javascript stops working after page-redirection (ANGULAR)

Tags: javascript, angular, redirect, angular6, routerlink

I'm using angular 6 to create a testimonial slider.
It looks great, but the problem is... I'm using RouterLink in my header, so everything loads at once. When you open the page with testimonial javascript for the first time it works, but then when you go onto another page and re-direct back it does not work.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue?

Is there a way to modify this function so it loads on page-view rather than page-load?

Thanks

JS  Code:

```
function mfnSliderTestimonials(){   

    var pager = function( el, i ){
        var img = $( el.$slides[i] ).find('.single-photo-img').html();
        return '<a>'+ img +'</a>';
    };

    $('.testimonials_slider_ul').each(function(){

        var slider = $(this);

        slider.slick({
            cssEase         : 'ease-out',
            dots            : true,
            infinite        : true,         
            touchThreshold  : 10,
            speed           : 300,

            adaptiveHeight  : true,             
            appendDots      : slider.siblings( '.slider_pager' ),
            customPaging    : pager,

            autoplay        : window.mfn_sliders.testimonials ? true : false,
            autoplaySpeed   : window.mfn_sliders.testimonials ? window.mfn_sliders.testimonials : 5000,

            slidesToShow    : 1,
            slidesToScroll  : 1
        });

    });
}
```

**EDIT: WORKS**
All working fine now. Even when re-routing. In thecomponent I've declared the javascript function in such way:

declare function YOURFUNCTION(): any;
@component......

ngOninit 
YOURFUNTION()

and obviously import * as $ from 'jquery'; was also necessary!

Thanks

Comment: why are you mixing angular 6 with jquery, dont kill it

Comment: It's only because I'm using a specific framework which has the testimonial j written for you. It works great, but as I said, it breaks on page re-direction.

Comment: make use of angular life cycle hook `ngAfterContentInit()` or some what, please refer the documentation. Reinit jQuery method there. And try avoid jQuery in angular